# Using Expandable UITableView to show only one row

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I try to do so as in the picture shown in red square.

[image]

I need by clicking a user opens a plate and DatePicker.  For this I use Expandable UITableView (http://www.wannabegeek.com/?p=338). But I can not understand how to do so in the section could is one element (eg DatePicker) and by clicking on the section shows exactly DatePicker. Now, if at least two elements, then the string is not displayed as a section, but as just a string containing no more elements. And as if I did not change the size of the prototype cell size does not change and I can not see completely DatePicker. Now my DatePicker is behind the text of the cell (which is logical)

Two main questions: how to change the size of the cell, that is normal to see DatePicker and how to make that you can have only one item in the list
In StoryBoard I see:
[image]

In simulator:
[image]

May have the decision easier?

I use the code:

```
    // Exampl2eController.m

    #import "Example2Controller.h"

    @implementation Example2Controller

    @synthesize dataModel = _dataModel;

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style

{

self = [super initWithStyle:style];

if (self) {

// Custom initialization

}

return self;

}



- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

_dataModel = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:

[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Row 1a", @"Row 2a", @"Row 3a", nil],

[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Row 1b", @"Row 2b", nil],

[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Row 1c", @"Row 2c", @"Row 3c", @"Row 4c", nil],

[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Row 1d", nil],

nil];


}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView

{

// Return the number of sections.

return [_dataModel count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

if ([_dataModel count] == 0) {

return 0;

}

// Return the number of rows in the section.

return [[_dataModel objectAtIndex:section] count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RowCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell.textLabel.text = [[_dataModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// just change the cells background color to indicate group separation

cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:232.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];

return cell;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView cellForGroupInSection:(NSUInteger)section

{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GroupCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Group %d (%d)", section, [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]];

// We add a custom accessory view to indicate expanded and colapsed sections

cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ExpandableAccessoryView"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ExpandableAccessoryView"]];

UIView *accessoryView = cell.accessoryView;

if ([[tableView indexesForExpandedSections] containsIndex:section]) {

accessoryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

} else {

accessoryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);

}

return cell;

}

// The next two methods are used to rotate the accessory view indicating whjether the

// group is expanded or now

- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView willExpandSection:(NSUInteger)section {

UITableViewCell *headerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

headerCell.accessoryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI - 0.00001); // we need this little hack to subtract a small amount to make sure we rotate in the correct direction

}];

}

- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView willContractSection:(NSUInteger)section {

UITableViewCell *headerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:section]];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

headerCell.accessoryView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);

}];

}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.

- (BOOL)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return YES;

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView canEditSection:(NSInteger)section {

return YES;

}

// Override to support editing the table view.

- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

[tableView beginUpdates];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

// Delete the row from the data source

[[_dataModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// cellVisibleForIndexPath: isn't strictly required sicne the table view will determine if the

// the row at that indexPath is actually visible, and do the appropriate manipulation

if ([(ExpandableTableView *)tableView cellVisibleForIndexPath:indexPath]) {

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}

if ([[_dataModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count] == 0) {

[_dataModel removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

[tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

} else {

[tableView reloadSectionCellsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}

}

else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {

// Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view

}

[tableView endUpdates];

}

// Override to support rearranging the table view.

- (void)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath

{

}

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.

- (BOOL)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

// Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.

return YES;

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(ExpandableTableView *)tableView canRemoveSection:(NSUInteger)section {

return YES;

}


@end
```

Comment: Hello. Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is an ivar called: _ungroupSingleElement set it to false and then you disable this feature